# Validate and correct invalid emailid formats in C#

Tags: c#, validation

Is there a way we can validate and correct invalid format emailids in C#.I got a function which can only validate but not correction.Some emailds like "abc@def.com." can be corrected.I`m fetching all emailids from database and sending them a mail,if I just remove invalid emailids,the person may loose info,so instead of removing I thought of correcting the mailid and send him the mail.
Is there a way?Or a function to do this.???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you realized that what is the correct email id?

Comment: How can you ever determine what somebodys real address is? You can't create a mind reader in C# to guess, unless you have another table which your not telling us about or your explaining this incorectly.

Comment: @SMK:As I Specified in my post emailids like "abc@def.com." here extra "." after com is like invalid.It`s failing.This can be removed right???

Comment: This is format correction, not the mail ID correction.

Comment: so you can simply validate email id by regular expression.Google it,you found lot of good tutorials.

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Yeah I believe in wat you said.But atleast there are less cases where we can do some corrections.

Comment: @SMK:Yeah I found many,but only validations they have done,If invalid emailids found it`ll be removed.Atleast We can do some minor corrections instead of removing right???

Comment: You can validate those emails, meaning you have a list of all invalid once. Contact those people in an other way and tell them to update or correct there email. It is a hell of job, but once done and maintained there shouldn't be any more invalid emails and you system can contact everybody.

Comment: Well, there is no fool proof way of doing it. How would you correct a mail id - abc@efg@gmail.com. It could be either of abcefg@gmail.com or abc@efggmail.com. Thinks about it.

Comment: Take this example: `myname@mydomainname.co.`. How do you know if this should be `myname@mydomainname.co` (Colombia), or `myname@mydomainname.com`, or `myname@mydomainname.co.uk`? The person might have misspelled something, or just forgotten the last part, or cut it out by accident, or whatever. This is why I would rather just check if the address is valid or not. Sometimes we programmers can be _too_ clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check wheather the Mail domain exists for example like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12072/C-NET-DNS-query-component), you can check if the Email ends with an unvalid char like **"."** or **","** and remove this if found but you can not really *"correct"* wrong Emails by trying to change each char and check if the Email exists or not, and its not desired sicne you would find probably for each change you make an exissting Email adress which is not the one you really wish to reach.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.I don`t really need the correct emailid but instead of that I just have to correct it and send so that in my case it doesn`t throw error.And later if the emailids don`t exists it`ll return a mail saying "Mail Undelivered".

Comment: Well if the Mail doesnt Exist and the Domain does you will be informed about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the email address as a string, then you can manipulate the string.  In your example, that would be removal of the trailing period. Other than this simple example, I suggest that you think long and hard about how useful this will be.  What is the context? Can you pass the mail address back to a user to get the correct address, as opposed to your best guess?
Adding code will clarify your question.  From your question, I don't know why you assume you can only validate, as opposed to correcting the mail address string.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to do this. You may have a built-in guess system that will take care of common mistakes though.

For instance, if I type my email id as `abc@gmali.com`, you may change it to `abc@gmail.com`. This still does not guarantee that the email is is now correct.

Assume I had an email id as `abc@gmail.com` and intentionally I typed in `asd@gmail.com`. Now, there is no way you can correct it. With the same intention, if I type `asd@gmial.com`, your code might make it correct email id as `asd@gmail.com` which still is incorrect.

Essentially what you are looking for is called client side validation. What ever front end you have, place validation that check if email address is correct as per syntax. For verifying if the user has given his real email, send a mail to the given address with activation link and ask them to click on it if they want to use applciation.

Edit:

If you need to just format the emails in database, you can check for common mistakes using queries/external executable. These will validate the data against a valid format which then, can be changed. What are the options you have, technology wise, for doing this?

Comment: I guess the OP is talking about correcting the format of the mail Id's based on mail ID validation.

Comment: @danish:Forget about clientside validation,guess few mailids already present in database before you validate,and you are using the same to send.In this what you can suggest me??Remember there are invalid format emailids.

Comment: Updated the reply. Although first two paragraphs from original reply do cater to your problem. All I was mentioning is that you should try and restrict invalid data from coming in to database, if possible.

Comment: @danish:Thanks for the idea about queries.I`ll look into it.